# Audio don't play again on page refresh - React

Tags: reactjs, refresh

My audio is being played when componentDidMount(). BUT it's not being played again when page refresh, although componentDidMount() is called again. Any idea how to obligate the audio to play again when page refresh?

```
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.songsQuiz) {
      alert("componentDidMount");
      this.playNextSongHandler();
    }
  }
  playNextSongHandler = () => {
    if (this.state.songsQuiz[this.state.currentSong] && this.state.playSong) {
      this.state.songsQuiz[this.state.currentSong].play();
      return;
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be the store state hasn't been fully update on the state, ie: `playSong` is null before you calling them.
You might consider adding a `componentDidUpdate` or using `React.useEffect`

Comment: Thanks a lot. With componentDidUpdate it also didn't work. I just found a walk around solution redirecting the page to itself IF/WHEN page refreshed. Probably there is a better solution, but I'm glad it worked,
I did like this:
    if (window.performance) {
      if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
        alert("This page is reloaded");
        window.location.href = "/musicalquiz";
      } else {
        alert("This page is not reloaded");
      }
    }

Answer (score 0):

I just found a walk around solution redirecting the page to itself IF/WHEN page refreshed. Probably there is a better solution, but I'm glad it worked.
But now the page is being loaded two times. Hope someone comes up with a better solution.
I did like this:

```
if (window.performance) {
  if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
    alert("This page is reloaded");
    window.location.href = "/musicalquiz";
  } else {
    alert("This page is not reloaded");
  }
}
```